# First Smart Contract: How to emit exact string data?

Tags: contract-design, contract-debugging

So I've written my first smart contract and deployed it onto the Ropsten test network, which is a simple program to write "hello world" into the data field when deployed.

```
pragma solidity 0.8.7;

contract Hello {
    
    event SayHello(string str);
    
    constructor() public {
        emit SayHello("Hello world!");
    }
}
```

However, when I check my contract address (0xc1c38A65BB311Bd0994edCa0896f35728306d190) on https://ropsten.etherscan.io and I navigate to see the data field, I see this:

```
0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c48656c6c6f20776f726c64210000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

which when formatted to (a mix of numbers and) text, I get:

```
3212Hello world!
```

My question is where did these leading characters (3212) come from? Is that part of the package when emitting events in any smart contract or is there a way I can clean up the data so only my intended message "Hello world!" is printed into the data field? If not, if we suppose I were to programmatically obtain the data field from transactions, how would I be able to separate the user-created data from the rest of the noise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I think those are:

- memory or data slot starts at byte 20
- data length in your case 12 bytes
- then what is inside the memory/data  bytes="48 65 6c 6c 6f 20 77 6f 72 6c 64 21" which is your "Hello world!"

you can use web3js or etherjs to decode the parameters

There are many ways and methods to do that, one of those (tested using remix):

> web3.eth.abi.decodeParameters(['string'],'0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000c48656c6c6f20776f726c64210000000000000000000000000000000000000000');
>
> > { "0": "Hello world!", "**length**": 1 }

https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.11/web3-eth-abi.html#decodeparameters